# SAGA GIS - raster image from Civil 3D

Tags: raster, saga, civil3d

I am a new user of SAGA GIS software.
I need to interface the Civil 3D 2015 and Hec Ras software in order to create a flooding map.
In order to put in communication the two softwares, I have to use the SAGA 2.1.0.

From the Civil 3D, I create a geotiff file (*.tif) and I've tried to import it into SAGA (with the command `GDAL/OGR - GDAL:Import Raster`).

Unfortunately, SAGA doesn't import the file and shows this error message:

> "Parameters file could not be imported"
>
> "XML parsing error:'syntax error' at line 1.

Can someone help please?

Comment: this works fine for me. what parameters are you using for the geotiff export? you could also try ticking the "create world file". But mine works without the world file. please indicate what version of civil, saga you are using.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. i have exported the geotiff file from the civil 3d 2015 and i'm using the Saga GIS 2.1.0.

Comment: do you think that i can use an other gis open source?

Comment: please read the http://gis.stackexchange.com/help FAQ consider posting an answer if you found one and mark it (the question) as answered. Then you can ask another question.

Comment: ok Brad, can you explain better what to do?

Comment: edit your original question and tell us what version of civil3d. also tell us what version of saga. Then edit your question and tell us what parameters you are using in civil when you export the geotiff.  like this... http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/133266/export-georeferenced-image-from-autocad-to-gis/133303#133303 Using the help you should be able to form a good question. If you have an answer, you can answer your own question by posting an answer. Then you can mark the answer as the correct answer.

Comment: Try exporting a small portion of your area and post the file here.